# Best way to sync data between IOS devices

Tags: ios

I am developing an app where i need to sync data between several devices with the main datastore being a central server.
So one instance of app on a device will get new data, send it to server, i then need to send this data to the other devices.

Issue i have is, how best or what is the standard way to trigger the data download?

1) Have each device poll the server every x time to make sure its data is up to date?

2) Have a separate thread constantly waiting for new data and when the server receives new data it pushes it out to the devices?

3) When the server receives new data it sends out push notifications which when the devices receives this, it causes the app to sync with the new data?

4) Something i ain't thought about

I know all three will potentially 'work' but i wondered if there is a standard architecture / method to doing what i want to achieve.

::Edit::
The data needs to be fairly 'instant' if i poll it then i'll have to poll it every 30 seconds max to achieve the sync rate i ideally want.

I can send the data to my server no problem at all, i can even download the data once i have the trigger to, its just the mechanism that triggers the download I'm unsure off.

I imagine that new data will be sent to the sever properly on an hourly basis.

Thanks

Comment: I think it greatly depends on your needs. How current does the info need to be? Are users going to be editing the data at the same time on all of the devices? Are you asking about how to connect them to a database? Are you looking for a database to use? Sounds like you should be using `CloudKit`

Comment: @vadian good use of spaces

Comment: Polling ... yuck. Web sockets?